# Compressing log files

Tags: logging

Is there any drawback of applying NTFS compression on IIS and Moss/Sharepoint (version 2007 and 2010) log files ?

I guess this won't be an issue. There will be a slight CPU overhead, but a great reduction of file used space (I'm expecting to divide by 4 the log files) and even a better file i/o performances (less data to write).

Am I right ?

I'd appreciate your feedbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010, this is done automatically (if you're referring to the ULS logs).  In SharePoint 2007, I don't see a downside except for the slight CPU overhead which should be negligible on a modern CPU.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to compress the log files on preproduction farm at first. Thanks